# Oracle Stored Procedure not Returning Results

Tags: oracle

My Oracle Stored Procedure does not return any results. I have tested the query outside the SPROC and it seems to return values. I have a feeling it has something to do with how I'm passing the sample and test parameters - because if I hardcode the sampleNumber and testNumber parameters in the Stored Proc, the results are returned correctly. I have pasted the Procedure and the PLSQL Declaration. I am very new to writing Oracle Procedures and any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTANALYSIS
    (vOrderNumber IN VARCHAR2
    , vTestNumber IN NUMBER
    , vSampleNumber IN NUMBER
    ) 

    AS

    anVar VARCHAR2(50) := NULL;

    BEGIN

    SELECT T.ANALYSIS INTO anVar FROM TEST T JOIN SAMPLE S
    ON T.SAMPLE_NUMBER = S.SAMPLE_NUMBER
    WHERE T.TEST_NUMBER = vTestNumber
    AND S.SAMPLE_NUMBER = vSampleNumber
    AND S.ORDER_NUM = vOrderNumber;

    dbms_output.put_line(anVar);

    END TESTANALYSIS;


    --PL SQL Call 
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
    EXEC TESTANALYSIS('4200010061', 720000050516, 14789)
    /
```

Comment: Yes, sorry about that - its a copy-paste issue. Yes, the numbers are definitely in the correct order.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong then. Maybe you can add the working version with the hard-coded values to the question, just in case that shows something you're missing. I'm not sure what else to suggest really. DO you get a `no_data_found` when you `exec` it, or does it complete and just not show the output?

Comment: It was my mistake. The database had not refreshed completely. Since I was running the SPROC from a different location, I was getting discrepancies in the result. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just out of interest, do you mean you had uncommitted data and you were getting different results in different sessions because of that?